# Möbius inversion formula and roots of unity

Tags: nt.number-theory, roots-of-unity, mobius-inversion

Is the exact value of
$$
 \sum_{d\mid n} \mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) \zeta^d
$$
known? Here, $\mu$ denotes the Möbius function and $\zeta$ a root of unity. At first sight, it seems to me that this should be known, but I didn't manage to find the solution yet.

Comment: This is, almost by definition, $nM(\zeta,n)$, where $M$ is the [necklace polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_polynomial). I have no idea if this value has any more explicit description.

Comment: I suppose that there is no trivial answer to my question yet. I was not aware of the necklace polynomial, but thanks to the above comment of @Wojowu, the paper by Trevor Hyde caught my attention: https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.08601. There, Hyde describes conditions under which $M(x,n)$ has factors of the form $x^m \pm 1$. So there are some criterions given under which $M(\zeta,n)$ vanishes, but this is far from computing $M(\zeta,n)$...

Comment: The name of [the paper by Trevor Hyde](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360596/möbius-inversion-formula-and-roots-of-unity#comment908513_360596): [Hyde - Cyclotomic factors of necklace polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.08601).

Answer (score 2):

In case of the root of unity is fixed one for all,

From the orthogonality of Dirichlet characters you can decompose the **periodic** sequence $n\to \zeta_{p^k}^n $ as a linear combination of the $\chi(\frac{n}{p^j}) 1_{p^j | n}, j\le k,\chi\bmod p^{k-j}$ (the coefficients of the linear combination are Gauss sums).

From $\zeta_N= \prod_{p^k \| N}\zeta_{p^k}^{a(p^k)}$ you get
$$\zeta_N^n = \sum_{l|N}\sum_{\chi\bmod \frac{N}l} b(\chi) \chi(\frac{n}{l})1_{l| n}, \qquad  b(\chi)=\frac1{\varphi(N/l)}\sum_{n=1}^{N/l} \overline{\chi(n)} \zeta_N^{nl}$$
from which the Dirichlet convolution 
$$\mu\star{\zeta_N} (n)=\sum_{d| n} \mu(n/d)\zeta_N^n $$
takes the explicit form $$= \sum_{l|N}\sum_{\chi\bmod \frac{N}l} b(\chi)  (\chi\star\mu)(\frac{n}{l})1_{l| n}=\sum_{l|N}\sum_{\chi\bmod \frac{N}l} b(\chi)1_{l| n}\prod_{p^r\| \frac{n}{l}} (\chi(p^r)-\chi(p^{r-1}))$$

Comment: … is that explicit?

Comment: If you don't tell what is unclear to you then I can't comment. The formula is messy but it is the formula, think to an arbitrary sum of multiplicative functions and the information you loose when not noticing it is.

Comment: It's less that it's unclear and more that it's not what I would call explicit, but, of course, that's a judgement call.

Comment: Well I don't agree, it is a finite sum of simple multiplicative functions, in what sense isn't that explicit. The original formula is shorter but it is not quite possible to guess its behavior for $n$ large.